# Cannot connect two different networks on rhel6 on 2 virtual NIC's

Tags: routing, nic, rhel6

I have a RHEL6 machine on VMware with 2 Virtual NIC's.

The output of the ip's and networks are as below:

```
$ ip a|grep "inet"

inet 192.168.17.128/24 brd 192.168.17.255 scope global eth0
inet 192.168.47.128/24 brd 192.168.47.255 scope global eth1
```

The netstat code for the same machine is:

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt     Iface
192.168.17.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0   eth0
192.168.47.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.17.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

The cat from sysctl.conf is as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sysctl.conf
# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
```

i have a second VM rhel6 machine with IP 192.168.17.129 and I am able to ping 192.168.17.128 on first one easily.

I need to ping | connect to 192.168.47.128 as well from the second machine.

How to get this done?

Comment: Use a static route?

Comment: @ Michael Hampton Yes i am trying for a static route